# Delete backup file in transact-sql during database copy/restore

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a "copy" stored procedure for a database.  During the copy, I backup the database with something like:

```
exec('backup database [' + @source + '] ' + 
      'to disk = N''' + @backupdir + '\copybackup'' ' +
      'with noformat, noinit, name=N''copybackup-full'', ' + 
      'SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;');
```

And then create and empty database, and restore to it:

```
exec('create database [' + @dest + '];');

exec('restore database [' + @dest + '] ' + 
      'from disk = N''' + @backupdir + '\copybackup'' ' + 
      'with file = 1, ' +
      'move N''' + @source + ''' to N''' + @dbdir + '\' + @dest + 
                 '.mdf'', ' +
      'move N''' + @source + '_log'' to N''' + @dbdir + '\' + @dest +
                 '_log.ldf'', ' +
      'NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10;');
```

So all is well and good.  Except, now I'm left with a file at @backupdir\copybackup that I really don't want.  How do I get rid of it?

Since this is a stored procedure, I *really* don't want to have to wrap it all in a batch file or some other hokey thing on the server itself.  I'd like to take care of it from T-SQL right here when I create the mess in the first place.  I've grepped through the MS Docs, but no joy.  (SQL Server 2005, please)

Ideas?

Comment: @casperOne: Don't edit my code.  Not your post, not your code, and you screwed up the last line of indenting anyway.  Hands off.

Comment: @clintp: Not your place to indicate who and who does not edit the post.  See the FAQ for more details.

Comment: Dont' care.  It's rude.  There's allowable, and then there's manners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to use T-SQL straight up to do this.  If there was a way for T-SQL to delete files on the filesystem, that would be a very bad thing.

You have two options if you want to keep this in SQL Server.  More than likely, the Microsoft Scripting Library is installed.  You could use the sp_OA* stored procedures to create an instance of the Scripting.FileSystemObject and then delete the file.

However, this is a bad idea, since SQL Server can't really protect itself against malicious code in this case and it can't dictate memory management in the server process either.

The preferred solution would be to create a CLR stored procedure which will take the path of the file that you wish to delete and then use the classes in the System.IO namespace to delete the file (using the File or FileInfo classes).

This way, SQL Server can sandbox the execution of the CLR stored procedure, and it also has control over memory management of the CLR.

Comment: xp_cmdshell would do it, too.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Yes, it would, but it suffers from the same security and resource management problems that calling the sp_OA* stored procedures have.

Comment: @casperOne: I'll probably do the CLR stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the following:

```
exec sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'temp backup device', 'temp_backup_device.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE [XXX] TO  [temp backup device] WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

RESTORE DATABASE [bububu] FROM  [abcosting temporary backup] WITH  FILE = 1,  KEEP_REPLICATION,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10

exec sp_dropdevice 'temp backup device', 'delfile'
```

But due to some bug (probably), the sp_dropdevice even with the 'delfile' option does not delete the underlying file, and no error is reported. But it might work in your configuration.

Comment: `sp_dropdevice` is not experiencing a bug, here is what MSDN says about it: `Drops a database device or backup device from an instance of the SQL Server 2005 Database Engine, deleting the entry from master.dbo.sysdevices.`